# When creating a fieldtype how do I provide methods to be used in the templates?

Tags: plugin-development, fieldtypes

I have created a fieldtype that saves a single integer to the database, it has some settings that defines the maximum value that integer can be:

```
protected function defineSettings()
{
  return array(
    'maxNumber' => array(AttributeType::Number, 'min' => 2, 'default' => 12)
  );
}
```

What I want to do when outputting my field in the templates is something like this:

```
The value is {{ entry.myField }} of {{ entry.myField.maxNumber }}
```

Anyone have any ideas? Do I need to create a data class like the options-based fields use or something? I'm just stabbing around in the dark here...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like plugins, fieldtypes can have their own settings as you're aware but while you can grab your plugin settings from pretty much anywhere, fieldtypes are a little more contextual.

In any case, like @Bryan pointed out, your fieldtype needs to implement `prepValue($value)` and ideally return a model containing the value as defined in `defineAttributes()` and the `maxNumber` as a property.

This basically means that when Craft calls your fieldtype's `prepValue($value)` which it does when the value of your field is needed (editing/outputting) you can return a model with the `value` and `maxNumber`.

---

**EDIT:**

```php
// MyFieldType.php
public function prepValue($value)
{
    $model = new MyFieldModel;

    $model->setAttribute('value', $value);
    $model->setMaxNumber($this->getSettings()->getAttribute('maxNumber'));

    return $model;
}
```

```php
// MyFieldModel.php
// Explicit getter/setter for $maxNumber rather than defining it as an attribute
protected $maxNumber;

public function setMaxNumber($value)
{
    $this->maxNumber = $value;
}

public function getMaxNumber()
{
    return $this->maxNumber;
}

public function defineAttributes()
{
    return array(
        'value' => AttributeType::Number,
    );
}
```

```twig
// _entry.html or other template name
{{ entry.myFieldHandle.value }}
{{ entry.myFieldHandle.maxNumber }}
```

[@selvinortiz](http://twitter.com/selvinortiz)

Comment: Great thanks Selvin! Where would the field model live? In the actual models directory or in the fieldtypes one?

Comment: In the models directory so that craft can autoload it for you.

Comment: It would be in models. @Selvin, I would be concerned about not returning a number with the __toString. Wouldn't __invoke be preferred so you can return it as the right type?

Comment: Thanks @SelvinOrtiz - I'll have a look tomorrow and let you know how I get on!

Comment: @Bryan if `__toString()` is a concern then @Josh can implement a `getValue()` method on the model and use it as {{ entry.myField.value }} which I would prefer over `__invoke()` since there is enough magic happening in Yii already.

Comment: @SelvinOrtiz I've tried your method today but I'm getting `Object of class Craft\MyFieldModel could not be converted to int` - is this when I need the `getValue()` thing? If so, how do I use it? I've tried a few random stabs but no luck...

Comment: FYI I've been going for the `{{ entry.myField.settings.maxNumber }}` route.

Comment: If you've implemented it the way I outlined it in my answer and want to get maxNumber like this `{{ entry.myField.settings.maxNumber }}` then you can implement a `getMaxNumber()` on the model that returns that value and Yii should take care of the rest.

Comment: I'll run through a few tests with a dummy fieldtype right now to ensure that we solve this in the cleanest way possible.

Comment: Hey @joshangell,
I just updated my answer with a more verbose code/workflow example. Let me know if it helps!

Comment: Thanks for this man - that does work but now if I just try `{{ entry.myFieldHandle }}` I get a bunch of crazy output: http://cl.ly/image/1u0T2M3a3U24.

`{{ entry.myFieldHandle.value }}` works though. I'm assuming this is the part where I need a `__toString()` or something? If I do implement one of those on my model I get the `could not be converted to int` error...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15295/discussion-between-joshangell-and-selvin-ortiz).

Comment: Ok I'm just going to mark this as correct even though I still haven't solved it - I think there must be something else going on in my plugin preventing `__toString()` from working as expected.

Comment: Hey Josh, sorry I didn't get to this sooner. I'd love to take a look at your code (if you can share it) and see how I can help you solve this for good. Feel free to reach me over hangout if you see me online or email me.

Answer (score 1):

To do this as you describe, you would need to add the [prepValue](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/field-types#modifying-your-fieldtypes-stored-data-for-use) function to your field type. You would then need to create a PHP class to fill with your field value and settings.

I'm not sure that it would work, but I also suggest adding the __invoke() method. You could use it to return the field value when you use the object as a variable (though Twig would call it as a method I think).

Comment: Could you expand a bit on how the php class part would work? I did end up trying that and basing my code of the OptionsData class but couldn't for the life of me work out how to use it - Yii didn't seem to know about my class when I called it like so `new MyPlugin_FieldTypeData`